# How can I break the text in one cell of system of equations?

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I'm new to Latex and encountered this problem.
I need your help to write the equation in the picture but cannot break the line in the 2nd cell of the 2nd row.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
    a=\frac{b}{c},&b\in[c,100]\\
    d=\frac{a-b}{c},&a\in[0,k],b\in[0,c]\\
    \end{cases}.
\end{equation}
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community...

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using `cases` you are loading the `amsmath` package. Then you can use a nested `aligned` environment (though a simple `array` would do too). I suggest using the `dcases` environment from mathtools in order to have larger fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
a=\frac{b}{c},   & b\in[c,100] \\
d=\frac{a-b}{c}, & \begin{aligned}
                   a&\in[0,k], \\
                   b&\in[0,c]
                   \end{aligned}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I have not understood the question. I have upvoted you, before. :-)

Comment: This answer solved my problem, thank you Campa!